# regex not working, accepting almost all letter number combinations

Tags: php, regex

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong? This is accepting everything as a match.

```
if (preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-z][a-z][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9]|15[0-1]:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-6][0-9]|17[0-6]/", $_GET['id']))
 {
 echo "match";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "no match";
 }
```

i'm wanting it to only match if the 1st letter is a capital A-Z, the 2nd letter a small letter a-z, the third letter a small letter a-z, then a number between 1 and 150, a colon :, Then a number between 1 and 176.  It should match Abc150:176  Zyx1:1  But not aBc151:177

Comment: Can you put some examples, what it should match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]{2}(?:[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-4][0-9]|150):(?:[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-6][0-9]|17[0-6])$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/nV6dF3).

- `^` asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `[A-Z][a-z]{2}` matches one upper-case and two lower-case letters
- `(?:[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-4][0-9]|150)` matches a number from 1 to 150
- `:` matches a colon
- `(?:[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-6][0-9]|17[0-6])` matches a number from 1 to 176
- `$` asserts that we are at the end of the string

In php:

```
$regex = "~^[A-Z][a-z]{2}(?:[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-4][0-9]|150):(?:[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-6][0-9]|17[0-6])$~";
echo (preg_match($regex,$string)) ? "***Match!***" : "No match";
```

Comment: Works perfect!  Thank you very much. I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer up yet.  Sorry.  But did click the check mark.

Comment: Thanks, see you next time! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the expressions around your alternation operator (|) in parens, otherwise it matches EVERYTHING to the left and right. As you have it now, it matches Aaa1 or 10 when you mean Aaa1 or Aaa10. Try:

```
/^[A-Z][a-z][a-z]([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9]|15[0-1]):([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-6][0-9]|17[0-6])/
```